# error on adding a directive for autosizing ion-textarea

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to provide an ion-textarea in my ionic application. The issue i am facing is that i could not increase the height of textarea. After searching i found out a solution for auto sizing the textarea by creating a directive from this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40850483/8231819

But i am getting an error like:

[image]

my Directive code :

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
selector: "ion-textarea[autoresize]" // Attribute selector
})
export class Autoresize {
  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target"])
  onInput(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {
    this.adjust();
  }

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adjust();
  }

  adjust(): void {
    let ta = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector("textarea");
    ta.style.overflow = "hidden";
    ta.style.height = "auto";
    ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

my HTML is:

```
  <ion-textarea autoresize [(ngModel)]="description"></ion-textarea>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Autoresize } from '../directives/autosize/autosize';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Autoresize
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Autoresize,
    {provide: ErrorHandler,useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Auth,
    ApiServiceProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**UPDATE**

I added following code inside the adjust function

```
console.log(this.element.nativeElement); 
console.log(this.element.nativeElement.querySelector("textar‌​ea"));
```

Now the log is: 1st one is printing and second one is null!

[image]

Comment: `Autoresize` _shouldnt_ be set in providers array..

Comment: @SurajRao I think i put that in providers array!

Comment: Please add `console.log(this.element.nativeElement); console.log(this.element.nativeElement.querySelector("textarea"))` to your `adjust()` and show the log

Comment: @Duannx. Updated the code. Please check

Comment: as mentioned in the answer where you got the code, you need check if `ta` exist before set style for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your adjust method as below, it will work :)

```js
adjust(): void {
    let ta = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector("textarea");
    if (ta) {
      ta.style.overflow = "hidden";
      ta.style.height = "auto";
      ta.style.height = ta.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked !! Thank you!!