# ion-textarea height collapses onblur

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-textarea` element with `autoGrow="true"` and `rows="8"`. If you click on the ion-textarea, don't enter any text, then loose focus (onBlur), the ion-textarea height collapses.

My guess is that in this case the "autoGrow" attr dominates the "row" attr but I would love a workaround for this as it pretty much breaks the UI (the user has no idea where the text box went)

This happens primarily when running ionic on android (sometimes on iOS and can't repro it on web).

Screenshots:

1. Initial state
   [initial_state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLdfi.png)
2. Collapsed
   [image: collapsed]

Here's the ionic docs for `ion-textarea` for ref: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/textarea

Code:

```
       <ion-textarea
            rows="8"
            autoGrow="true"
            autocapitalize="on"
            autocorrect="on"
            formControlName="body"
            placeholder="Write your message... "
            [ngClass]="{
              invalid: body.invalid && body.touched
            }"
          >
      </ion-textarea>
```

[EDIT] other answers like [Auto growing textarea in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480224/auto-growing-textarea-in-ionic) are focused on implementing the autoGrow feature which is now built into ionic (and I'm using). Here there's some error in using `autoGrow` and `rows` attributes together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto growing textarea in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480224/auto-growing-textarea-in-ionic)

Comment: No, ionic now has a built in autoGrow attribute which I'm using that effectively does what that is trying to accomplish. This is about an error or bug in how autoGrow interacts with the rows attribute (also built into the ionic lib)

Comment: Does it helps? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/strange-behaviour-of-ion-textarea-with-auto-grow/175353/3

Comment: Seems related but not a real solution

Comment: Setting a `min-height` using CSS might work.

Comment: @Thomas I tried, it applies to the ion-textarea element but the child textarea element doesn't inherit it and I don't seem to be able to target it with css.

Comment: Why not? As far as I can see `ion-textarea` is not using shadow dom so you should be able to target it with `ion-textarea textarea {}`.

Comment: There is `#shadow-root (open)` above `ion-textarea` but not inside it.